# Android ListView displays ListSelector only after scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I added a simple `ListSelector` to the `ListView`.
The Problem is, that the `ListSelector` is only displayed, after the ListView is scrolled a little.

How can I make the `ListSelector` to apear immediately on select?

**ListView**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonEntwerten" 
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
/>
```

**@drawable/list_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector__gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check out how android has configured it, and change it accordingly (file name is "list_selector_background.xml") :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />

</selector>
```

in short, you just have to handle the state_pressed state . the rest are good states to handle too.

the problem in your code is that it has no states.

Comment: I did not add any states for the case of simplicity, so that the BG apears in any state. This worked. The problem is - the BG does not apear IMMEDIATELY, but just after I scroll the ListView a little.

Comment: so why using selectors at all? they are used for states. if you want a static background, you can set it for each item in the listView and set the background of the listView (and whatever its container is, even if it's the window itself) to transparent... i think you should watch the lecture "the world of listView" : http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: I will use different states. I suppose, that my problem does not depend on states, so I took them out to provide a simple example.

Comment: so don't use it. use any of the other solutions i've written. a selector is used to select the correct drawable based on a state : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList